# Circular dependency issue with setup script

Tags: python, python-3.x, versioning, dependency-management, setup.py

I'm writing a python `setup.py` script for an own package which needs a version constant from the package. However, the package needs to have some dependencies installed.
Therefore I specified `install_requires` in the `setup.py`.
However, when I generate the package via `python setup.py sdist` and install it in another project I get a dependency error.
What am I doing wrong, here?
When I dismiss the import statements from the `__init__.py` file, the dependencies (in this case `pyzmq` and `jsonpickle`, but could be any other dependencies) are installed correctly in the other project.

**folder-structure**

```
myproject/
   | setup.py
   | mypackage/
     | __init__.py
     | some_code.py
     | version.py
```

**`__init__.py`**

```
from . import some_code
from . import version
```

**some_code.py**

```
import jsonpickle
import zmq

from mypackage.version import VERSION

print(f"Version is {VERSION}")
```

**setup.py**

```
import [...]
from distutils.dir_util import remove_tree
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

# Globals definitions used more than one time
PACKAGE_NAME = "mypackage"

[...]

 
from mypackage.version import VERSION  # <<<<---- This is the command which is problematic !!!!!


setup(name = PACKAGE_NAME,
    version = VERSION,
    author = "Me",
    author_email = "I@me.de",
    description='mypackage test',
    include_package_data = True,
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=[
    'pyzmq', 'jsonpickle'
    ],
    zip_safe = False)
```

**In another project**

```
(.venv) user@l-user:~/PycharmProjects/using_mypackage$ python -m pip install mypackage-3.4.6.tar.gz 
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple
Processing ./mypackage-3.4.6.tar.gz
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 255:
   command: /home/user/PycharmProjects/using_mypackage/.venv/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-4upmamin/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-4upmamin/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-w7plcisg
       cwd: /tmp/pip-req-build-4upmamin/
  Complete output (9 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-req-build-4upmamin/setup.py", line 3, in <module>
      from mypackage.version import VERSION  # <<<<---- This is the command which is problematic !!!!!
    File "/tmp/pip-req-build-4upmamin/mypackage/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
      from . import some_code
    File "/tmp/pip-req-build-4upmamin/mypackage/some_code.py", line 1, in <module>
      import jsonpickle
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jsonpickle'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The legacy "canonical" solution has been to use a regexp to find the line with `VERSION` and `ast.literal_eval` the string on that line with something like

```
with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "mypackage", "__init__.py")) as infp:
    version = ast.literal_eval(
        re.search("^VERSION = (.+?)$", infp.read(), re.M).group(1)
    )
```

This works until it doesn't (but happily it will break loudly when someone tries to run setup.py).

However, if you don't need `setup.py` at all (though based on the fact that you're referring to `remove_tree` and probably using it in the part you've elided, you might?), you could switch altogether to having no imperative `setup.py` at all, by switching to PEP 517 builds; `setuptools` has nice machinery to let you just do `version = attr:mypackage.VERSION`.

[`packaging.python.org` has a great step-by-step tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/#creating-pyproject-toml) on that. You may also find [my `setuppy2cfg` converter tool useful](https://github.com/akx/setuppy2cfg).

Comment: I think my misunderstanding was that I've overseen that the `setup.py` script is actually used two times. At first to generate the `tar.gz`, at second to install the package in the other project. I've overseen the second.

Comment: Yeah, setup.py has this twin (or more) personality. With PEP517-compliant packages and `build` from PyPI, all you need is `python -m build .` to get a .tar.gz and a .whl, and modern versions of `pip` deal fine with PEP517 too, setup.py or no setup.py.

Comment: I tried your script and it provided me a `setup.cfg` in my test project (the version string is `VERSION = "3.4.5"`). However in the real project I got the error message: `*** Unable to get value for ('metadata', 'version'): malformed node or string: <_ast.Attribute object at 0x7f4582da17f0>`. The version in this case is: `BLABLA_VERSION = "0.8.90"`. Did I broke some naming convention?

Comment: It's not perfect in the least – you will need to modify those bits by hand; for your case, add `version = attr:blabla.BLABLA_VERSION` (if the package is `blabla`).

Comment: That's OK. I'm glad I can use your tool, anyway. It gave me a good starting point to fiddle out those details. Thanks.

Comment: It's now working using `setup.cfg` instead of `setup.py`. `setup.py` is past, now.